# Spring java based configuration for custom error pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a `CustomErrorHandler` bean that extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` as a replacement for xml based configuration for handling custom error pages.The bean class is registered inside `WebInitializer`
which is a `web.xml` equivalent.The problem is that i am unable to view the custom error pages that i have designed when a '404' exception is occurred or any of those that i have configured to handle in the bean class.

This is the code for my `CustomErrorHandler` bean class and `WebInitializer`:

CustomErrorHandler.java:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver;

public class CustomHandlerExceptionResolver extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CustomHandlerExceptionResolver.class);

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse response,
                                              Object handler,
                                              Exception ex) {
        try {

            if (ex instanceof java.lang.Throwable) {

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/uncaughtException");
            } else if (ex instanceof java.lang.Exception) {

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/uncaughtException");
            } else if (response.getStatus()==404) {

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/resourceNotFound");
            } else if (response.getStatus()==500) {

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/resourceNotFound");
            }             //end webflow
            //error 500
            else if (ex instanceof org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException) {
                logger.warn("applicationcontextexception");
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/resourceNotFound");
            }
            //end error 500

            //default
            return super.doResolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception handlerException) {
            logger.warn("Handling of [" + ex.getClass().getName() + "] resulted in Exception", handlerException);
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

WebInitializer.java:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;
import javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import com.knowesis.sift.service.util.PropertyFileReader;

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Autowired
    PropertyFileReader propertyfilereader;



    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        Set<SessionTrackingMode> modes = EnumSet.noneOf(SessionTrackingMode.class);
        modes.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
       // ctx.register(PropertyFileReaderConfig.class);
       //   ctx.register(RootContext.class);
        ctx.register(SecurityConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
        //servletContext.addFilter("springExceptionFilter",ExceptionInterceptor.class);
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(modes);
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(ServletContextInitializer.class);

/**
here i have registered the custom handler
*/      
dispatcherContext.register(CustomHandlerExceptionResolver.class);

        Dynamic servlet=servletContext.addServlet("appServlet",new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);


    }

}
```

Is it that i need to use any other Handler class provided by spring or change my current configuration ?. I also might have made a silly mistake,so please forgive as i am new to spring framework.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: What happens exactly ? Is your custom error handler ignored or does any error end to `/uncaughtException` ?

Comment: @Serge Sorry i did'nt notice your comment.Custom error handler is ignored and at the same time none of the custom pages are resolved.

Comment: Now that i have configured this, i am not able to direct '404 not found' error to  specific error page.For this, i came to know that 'throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound' needs to be enabled in web.xml and i tested it with one demo and it worked.How to configure the same in java based configuration?-this is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering your class in the Spring context is not enough.

If you're using Spring > 3.1, you should have a confuguration class for your app somewhere. This class should be annotated with `@Configuration` and extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (or add `@EnableWebMvc`) which has all the basic configuration for a Spring MVC webapp.

To register your custom `HandlerExceptionResolver`, you should overide the `configureHandlerExceptionResolvers` method in your config class.

```
@Override
public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(
            List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
        exceptionResolvers.add(new CustomHandlerExceptionResolver());
        addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(exceptionResolvers);
}
```

Comment: i created a new class and override the method this way, but no expected result

Comment: Did you register this new config class in your Spring context?

Comment: yes ,like this--> dispatcherContext.register(ExceptionHandlerConfig.class);

Comment: Did you add your ExceptionResolvers like this?
(See edit in my answer)

Comment: yes but did not call addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(exceptionResolvers);

Comment: Not sure, it's required though

Comment: okay i tried with it as well, no result .If i am not wrong,this would override my CustomExceptionHandler with spring's default handler.

Comment: hey thanks its working.Even if i dont register my custom handler in webInitializer, it works.I just need to return the bean of the custom exception handler class that extends the 'DefaultExceptionHandler' class.

Comment: `addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers` does not exist.

Comment: @zygimantus yes it does : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers-java.util.List-